# F# nested list problems

Tags: list, f#, nested

I have a list such as

```
let stdCourseList = [(10,[100;101;102]); (11,[101]); (14,[]); (12,[100;101])];;
```

this is a list with student id and the list of course id

I want to implement a function that would be able to count the number of course that a student is taking.
such as if i do this

```
numbOfCourse(stdCourseList,10)
```

I would get 3 because student with id 10 took 3 course

So far i have this code:

```
let rec numbOfCourse = function
|(([], id)) -> 0
|(((id2:int,(y:int)::ys)::xs),id) ->
      if id=id2 then 1 //should a code to count the list of the course
      else numbOfCourse(xs,id);;
```

But when i run it i got this error

```
   let rec numbOfCourse = function
  ------------------------^^^^^^^^

  stdin(1471,25): warning FS0025: Incomplete pattern matches on this
  expression. For example, the value '([(_,[])],_)' may indicate a case not 
  covered by the pattern(s).
```

I dont really understand why i got this error and what the error means. Could someone please help me explain it? what are the best way to handle nested list?

Is this part wrong?

```
(((id2:int,(y:int)::ys)::xs),id)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is saying that your patterns are not exhaustive.  The example `([(_,[])],_)` indicates that your function does not handle the case where the course list consists of a single element and where the single element in the course list has an empty list as its second member.

The entire pattern is a tuple.  The second part of the tuple pattern will match any value; that's what the underscore means.  The first part of the tuple is the list with a single element:

```
[(_,[])]
```

The single element is a tuple:

```
(_,[])
```

The first part of that tuple will match any value; the second part matches the empty list.

If you know that you'll never get such a course list, you can ignore the warning, but I find it better to add a failure case when the compiler finds an incomplete pattern match, because then the compiler will inform me of additional cases that I've failed to cover.  For example, if you add this line to your function, you'll get another warning:

```
| ([(_,[])],_) -> failwith "unexpected pattern"
```

The warning is

> Incomplete pattern matches on this expression. For example, the value '([*;*],_)' may indicate a case not covered by the pattern(s).

In general, I find that trying to write complex patterns that decompose complex structures like lists of tuples of lists is treacherous.  It's best to treat one layer at a time:

```
let rec f = function
            | [], _ -> //your base case here
            | (studentId, courseList) :: tail, idParameter when studentId = idParameter -> //one recursive case here
            | _ :: tail, id -> // another recursive case here
```

If you need to decompose the list of course ids, you can use a separate `match` expression to do that, as part of the expression that replaces `one recursive case here`.  "Divide and conquer" will make it easier to reason about your code.

Still, if that is not an option because of your course requirements, it should be tractable to decompose this structure in one list.  Just treat each list as having two possible states: empty and not empty.  That will reduce the number of permutations.

Finally, you probably want to read about helper functions and about how to write tail-recursive functions, though it's possible that you are still at a point in your course where you should not be using them.  An important concept is that of the "accumulator."

Comment: Wow thank you very much sir, this is the answer that i've been looking for. i just found out that i could do that `idParameter when studentId = idParameter` and i need one more recursive case which is the `_::tail,id -> f(tail,id)`. you are awesome

Answer (score 1):

You could do this instead:

```
let getCourseCount idx l =
    l
    |> Seq.filter (fun (i, _) -> i = idx)
    |> Seq.map (fun (_, courses) -> courses |> Seq.length)
    |> Seq.sum
```

The `getCourseCount` function has the signature `'a -> seq<'a * #seq<'c>> -> int when 'a : equality`, so it's quite generic. It takes any sequence as input, as long as each element is a tuple, and the second element is another sequence.

The `stdCourseList` value fits the input type, since it's an `(int * int list) list`, and a `list` is a `seq`.

The `filter` function selects only those tuples where the first element is equal to the input `idx`.

There may be more than a single element that passes the filter (e.g. if there's two entries for *10*), but for each of these, the `map` function counts the number of courses using `Seq.length`.

Since there may be duplicate entries, `Seq.sum` can be used to add those numbers together.

FSI sample session:

```
> stdCourseList |> getCourseCount 10;;
val it : int = 3
> stdCourseList |> getCourseCount 11;;
val it : int = 1
> stdCourseList |> getCourseCount 14;;
val it : int = 0
> stdCourseList |> getCourseCount 12;;
val it : int = 2
```

Comment: thank you for the great answer sir. but the problem that was given by my teacher specificaly ask for a function that looks like so `getCourseCount(stdCourseList,id) : (int * int list) list * int -> int`.

Comment: @user142068 You can do the exact same thing using `List` module, but even then the signature will be more generic than what you listed. You can just manually constrain the parameters to whatever your desired signature should be.